# mysql php connection problem in windows 7

Tags: php, mysql, windows-7

i install windows7 ultimate and php 5.3.1 and mysql server 5.1

mysql server work fine from

```
                  mysql>
```

and if see phpinfo();

i get the following table

```
              mysql
       MySQL Support enabled 
      Active Persistent Links  0  
      Active Links  0  
      Client API version  mysqlnd 5.0.5-dev - 081106 - $Revision: 289630 $  
      Persistent cache enabled 
      put_hits  0  
      put_misses  0  
      get_hits  0  
      get_misses  0  
      size  2000  
       free_items  2000  
      references  2
```

but when i connect with following php command

```
   $db_host="localhost"; 
   $db_name="mysql";
   $db_user="root";
   $db_pass="*****"; 

   $dbc=mysql_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass) OR DIE (mysql_error());
   $dbs=mysql_select_db($db_name) OR DIE (mysql_error());
```

when i run page, page take long time in loading and then return nothing.
and if i pass any query it return false, i think its connection problem.

Thanks

Comment: You should review the Apache error log as it's probably some other kind of issue (I once had an issue with APC, then switched to VC9 compiled version).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost. Alternatively you can disable IPv6 or disable the IPv6 localhost alias in your HOSTS file.

Comment: its working fine with 127.0.0.1 why not working with localhost...?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to connect using pure php.exe, not web server.
What error message is shown?
Also maybe try '127.0.0.1' intsead of 'localhost'